# Modyfy .doc file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, doc

I'm trying to find any code working in the ASP.NET project that would be able to read, change the font, save the DOC file. Does anyone know any code to modify a DOC file format ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724765/manipulating-word-documents-on-server-without-office-installed-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 3rd party control for that, like Aspose.Words. Without a control you would need to use server-side Office automation which is highly not recommended.