# Error in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application #AZURE PORTAL FUNCTION APP

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I need to open and read the content (Eg : OLE Object) in word using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

I had done in visual studio by adding reference libraries.

While Creating the same in FUNCTION APP IN Azure Portal. It shows an error.

ERROR : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**********' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I had added .dll of office.

*#r"..\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.12.0.0\lib\net11\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll"*

*#r "..\Microsoft.Office.Core.12.0.0\Office.dll"*

When i create an object_reference for WORD it throws an error.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(); //It Throws the error here Document document = application.Documents.Open(tmpFile, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false);

please help me

Thanks

Comment: Word interop requires an installed copy of Word. Your function app doesn't have that. - _"The Interop library is not a "working" library in itself, it is only a wrapper around winword.exe for .NET programs,"_ [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724765/manipulating-word-documents-on-server-without-office-installed-asp-net#4724990)

Comment: I recommend using [Docx Exceed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/) or [OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)
To read and manipulate your file

Comment: I need to open RTF Files in c# . so that iam using interop.word . Is it possible to open RTF File in openXml ? @stuartd

Comment: Haven't used it myself but [it looks possible, yes](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/blob/master/src/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/Packaging/AlternativeFormatImportPartType.cs#L72), depending on what you mean by "open" the file.