# How to read data from CloudFile (Azure File Storage)?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage, file-storage

Have a problem to read data from CloudFile. I'm using Azure File Storage, .net core 2.1.
Try to read data from the file that was uploaded to File storage.
Get a reference to file, but don't understand what to do next. Try to use different solutions, but they not work

```
cloudFile = directoryReference.GetFileReference(fileName);
```

Can you please help how to work with it to read all data(text, etc.)?
Will have formats as .doc, .pdf, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Upd: I'm using OenXml to solve this problem. It's could work for .docx and .xlsx formats documents.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the text from your doc (this is from the example in the link below):

```
string text = cloudFile.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
```

Take a look at this. It explains how to use the storage API specifically the file storage API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use it, but it returns instead of correct text only character set(like - �(���� ). I have text in the file in English.
I think that I need encode result, using utf8 or utf16, but how to do it correct?
Thanks!

Comment: ahhhh i see. What file type is causing this .doc or .pdf?

Comment: Never had to do this before but did a search on google and it seems like your going to have to use an API.  Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724765/manipulating-word-documents-on-server-without-office-installed-asp-net/4724990#4724990

Comment: In this case, it was a .doc file. But later I will use .pdf files too.
Try to encode this by different solution, but it works not correct
Can you please advise how to do it correct? thanks

Comment: Thanks, will check it

Comment: If the data is not plain text, you can try `DownloadToStreamAsync` or `DownloadToByteArrayAsync` instead of `DownloadTextAsync`.